# SSIS: Error when executing a Execute Package Task

Tags: sql-server, ssis-2012

I have a project where I have 1 master package and several child packages which I call in the master.
However when I launch the master package it goes into error on one "Execute Package Task"
See below for the ouput from the Output-Window:

```
Information: 0x40016042 at build_NAV_sources: The package is attempting to configure from the parent variable "var_actual_timestamp".
.
.--more variables configuration
.
Information: 0x40016042 at build_NAV_sources: The package is attempting to configure from the parent variable "var_table_prefix".
Error: 0xC00220E0 at Execute Package Read Dim norriq data to sources: The connection is not specified.
Error: 0xC0024107 at Execute Package Read Dim norriq data to sources: There were errors during task validation.
Error: 0xC00220E4 at Execute Package build nav sources: Error 0xC0012050 while preparing to load the package. Package failed validation from the ExecutePackage task. The package cannot run.
.
Task failed: Execute Package build nav sources
SSIS package "F:\Workspaces\KPA\TFS\Norriq\BI\SQL 2012\NAV 2015\SSIS\NAV Datamart\build_NAV_datamart_master.dtsx" finished: Success.
```

When I check the package where it indicates that the connection is not specified I clearly see that there is an connection specified. In my connection manager I see the connection and when I edit this one and check for connectivity everything works fine.

To make it weirder: When I launch the package (build_NAV_sources) seperatly, it executes without any errors or warnings

Anyone has a clue on whats happening?

Thx

Comment: Without changing anything important, I've checked-in my solution in TFS, closed VS, opened the solution again and did a build/rebuild and it worked magically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without changing anything important, I've checked-in my solution in TFS, closed VS, opened the solution again and did a build/rebuild and it worked magically.